# Not getting request parameter value thru chrome/firefox. Related to double escaping?

Tags: java, html, tomcat, web-applications, encoding

Here is my link

```
"customer.action?custId=211&amp;custAddressId=2341";
```

This url string is the output of c:out tag in jsp.

In Firefox/Chrome I am getting the value of `custAddressId` as `null`. Reason I think(almost sure) is happening because Chrome/Firefox
are  escaping the already ecsaped value(thats why I am getting the second paramter name as `amp;custAddressId` instead of `custAddressId`)
but IE does not do that.

Is there a way i can configure my `tomcat 6` to get the right paramters(even if it is double escaped).
If not is there a way i can handle it in c:out or browser level itself where i do not need to browser specific code ?

Comment: Why don't you try using just `&` instead of `&amp;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no way you can configure Tomcat to do double unescaping. You need to make sure your client is sending the correct data.